# Am I able to show what my program is currently doing?

Tags: python, overflow

I am trying to run this python program in Canopy python editor in python2 and python3 and my slow school mac book takes an ample amount of time to run it and I'm not sure if it is actually doing something or if it just pausing.

```
import binascii

lower = 10**70
upper = 10**80

v = (lower+upper)/2
c = 2205316413931134031046440767620541984801091216351222789180593875373829950860542792110364325728088504479780803714561464250589795961097670884274813261496112882580892020487261058118157619586156815531561455215290361274334977137261636930849125

while True:
    p = pow(v, 3)
    if p < c:
        lower = v
    elif p > c:
        upper = v
    else:
        print(v)
        binascii.unhexlify(hex(v)[2:])
        exit()
```

The numbers I am using are pretty large so I tried shortening my variables to this:

```
lower = 10**7
upper = 10**8

v = (lower+upper)/2
c = 22053164
```

But even with smaller numbers I could not produce an output in time. I've interrupted the kernel after exactly 2 minutes to see where my program's overflow is and here's what I've learned:

Python 2 - Stoped at line 12

Python 2 ran in Kernel namespace - Stoped at line 10

Python 3 - Stoped at line 10

Python 3 ran in Kernel namespace - Stoped at line 9

Is there anyway I can make the program give me in output every couple minutes so I make sure it is still running? Or is there anything else I can try to get my program to speed up and still give me the output I need?

Comment: Write a bunch of print statements

Comment: It looks like this loop will never end unless it ends in the first iteration. The value of v, c, and p never change, so if you enter the `if` or `elif` blocks once, you'll keep entering them forever. You may be under the impression that changing the value of `lower` and/or `upper` will also cause the value of `v` to automatically change. This is not the case. As a simpler example, `a = 0; b = a + 1; a = 10; print(b)`, prints 1, not 11.

Comment: This was very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see what the program is doing is to insert a series of print statements in the code.

When you see what the console is showing you, you'll be able to grasp what's happening to your variables. Hint: p isn't changing and is looping forever.

```html
import binascii

lower = 10**70
upper = 10**80

v = (lower+upper)/2
c = 2205316413931134031046440767620541984801091216351222789180593875373829950860542792110364325728088504479780803714561464250589795961097670884274813261496112882580892020487261058118157619586156815531561455215290361274334977137261636930849125

print("Starting Loop")
while True:
    p = pow(v, 3)
    print("p value is now:", p)
    if p < c:
        lower = v
    elif p > c:
        upper = v
    else:
        print(v)
        binascii.unhexlify(hex(v)[2:])
        exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with my question! I added after upper=v to print v as well. Although, is there anyway way I can change the output from being printed in scientific notion and instead the full number so I can see if I made an error in my script? My program is printing 'p value is now: 1.2500000003749997e+239' and 'v value is now 5.0000000005e+79'. Is my program running the script with these rounded numbers or is it just not displaying the full value?

Comment: Also, when I changed lower to 10^7 when I was testing if smaller numbers could get me an output, I accidentally changed it back to 10^70 and it should be 10^79. Just realized now, sorry for my error. Changes outcomes 'p value is now: 1.2500000003749997e+239' and 'v value is now 5.0000000005e+79' to 'p value is now: 1.6637500000000002e+239' and 'v value is now 5.5e+79'

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep track of the wall time and print out something once in a while:

```
import binascii
import time

TIME_INTERVAL = 5  # Seconds
lower = 10**70
upper = 10**80

v = (lower+upper)/2
c = 2205316413931134031046440767620541984801091216351222789180593875373829950860542792110364325728088504479780803714561464250589795961097670884274813261496112882580892020487261058118157619586156815531561455215290361274334977137261636930849125

begin_interval = time.time()
while True:
    p = pow(v, 3)
    if p < c:
        lower = v
    elif p > c:
        upper = v
    else:
        print(v)
        binascii.unhexlify(hex(v)[2:])
        exit()
    if time.time() - begin_interval > TIME_INTERVAL:
        print('still running')
        begin_interval = time.time()  # Reset.
```